# Как продолжит запись видеопотока (webm, vp8) в уже существующий файл (средствами C#)?

Tags: javascript, c#, .webm

**Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:**
Со стороны клиента при помощи websocket гоню видео по кусочкам на сервер:

```
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
   if (ws && ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN && e.data && e.data.size > 0) {
      ws.send(e.data);
   }
   else {
      //...
   }
}
mediaRecorder.start(100);
```

На сервере в цикле получаю эти кусочки и пишу в файл.

```
while (true)
{
   buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[500000]);
   result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
   if (socket.State == WebSocketState.CloseReceived)
   {
      bw.Close();
      fs.Close();
      break;
   }
   if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count) == "start record")
   {
      writeStatus = "start record";
      fullPath = $"{context.Server.MapPath("~")}{fileName}.{fileExt}";
      fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
      bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
      continue;
   }

   if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count) == "stop record")
   {
      bw.Close();
      fs.Close();
      writeStatus = "none";
      continue;
   }

   if (writeStatus == "start record")
   {
      bw.Write(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);
      pos += result.Count;
   }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно при каждой перезагрузке страницы продолжать писать видео в тот же файл. Как я понимаю, просто дописывать в конец файла - не выход, так как в этом случае все дописанные байты не воспроизводятся при проигрывании записанного видеофайла. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно продолжить запись видео в тот же файл?

Comment: `Как я понимаю, просто дописывать в конец файла - не выход` Но, ведь судя по вашему коду именно это вы и делаете когда пишете куски видео в файл. Да и смысл спрашивать у комьюнити такой весьма специфичный вопрос, который проще самому быстро проверить.

Comment: Верно, именно свой код я и описывал тут. Предположу, что вы до вопроса не дочитали, поспешив дать не очень подходящий в данном случае ответ.